# Printing to stdout in Celery worker shows up as basic.qos: prefetch_count->X

Tags: celery

I have a periodic Celery task in which I make quite a bit of printing to stdout.

For example:

```py
print(f"Organization {uuid} updated")
```

All of these print statements look like this in my worker output:

`[2019-10-31 10:36:00,466: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->102`

The counter at the end is incremented for each print. Why is this? What would I have to change to see stdout?

I run the worker as such:

```
$ celery -A project worker --purge -l DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not call print() in your tasks. Instead, you have something like: `logger = get_task_logger(__name__)` and use logger in your tasks when you need to write something to the log at certain level.

Comment: I know I could do that, but the question is still 1. what is the basic.qos thing and 2. how can I see the output to stdout